# Reverse background-position animation without resetting

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, background-position

I created an animation with CSS that changes the `background-position` of an element over time, to create a sort of scrolling effect with the background.

```
@keyframes stars-animate {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 -500px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 2000px -500px;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. However, I also want to start to rewind the animation and create a reverse scrolling event. This is triggered by some irrelevant action.

```
function triggerReverse(element) {
    element.style.animationDirection = 'reverse';
}
```

However, when I set the `animation-direction` to *reverse*, it does work, but not before it flips the entire background.

Am I doing it wrong, or is that the wrong way to do it, and if so, what is the right way?

**Edit: I need to be able to reverse the animation while it is playing**

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

The renewed sample code below provide the effect that enables a user to interrupt/pause the animation (during the first iteration) and immediately start to reverse the animation.

Here it is using **time** to control. Record the elapsed time from the beginning of animation, and calculate how to start the reverse animation. There are **2** iterations defined in css to make a whole loop. Without user intervention, the animation pauses/stops after the first iteration. But if there is, pause the iteration and immediately re-start it with a calculated `animation-delay` time. This will looks like an immediate reverse, however actually it is a new start.

There is also a trick on how to re-start the animation. Please refer to the code comment.

I searched around but found nobody has mentioned a similar scenario so far, nor a similar solution. Instead of to use time to control, I would like to see other better approaches.

My test also proves that different running environments render slightly different smoothness. Fortunately, here in SO is the best.

Try the solution to see if it can works well in your own scenario.

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span'),
  button = document.querySelector('button'),
  duration = 10; // animation-during

let startTime;

span.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  startTime = Date.now();
  button.style.visibility = 'visible';
});

span.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => span.style.animationPlayState = 'paused');

span.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.classList.remove('my_anim');
  void span.offsetWidth; // safely apply changes
  span.classList.add('my_anim');
  const elapsed = Date.now() - startTime;
  const delay = (elapsed < duration * 1000) ? (elapsed / 1000 - duration * 2) : -duration;
  span.style.animationDelay = `${delay}s`;
  span.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
});
```

```css
span.my_anim {
  animation: 10s 2 alternate my_move;
}

@keyframes my_move {
  from {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
}

button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="my_anim">@</span>
</div>
<button>reverse</button>
```

---

This example does not use `background-position` for animation but a plain character.

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span"),
  button = document.querySelector("button");

span.addEventListener(
  "animationiteration",
  function() {
    this.classList.add("paused");
    button.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
);

button.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    this.style.visibility = "hidden";
    span.classList.remove("paused");
  }
);
```

```css
span {
  animation: 3s 2 alternate my_move;
}

span.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes my_move {
  from {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
}

button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>@</span>
</div>
<button>reverse</button>
```

**NB**: Use `-webkit-` prefix for css animation when necessary.

Comment: This is optimized and all, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: This doesn't work. I need to be able to reverse the animation while it's playing

Comment: @AceInteract: My understanding is that you expect an user action to stop the animation and then immediately start to reverse at the current position. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I need

Comment: @AceInteract OK. I'd updated my answer with an example working that way.

Comment: Still doesn't quite work. It flips again when I reverse it a second time. It needs to be able to reverse the animation and go back and forth at any given time

Comment: Still not it. It needs to be able to reverse it's state **at any given time**. Imagine it like those automatic doors. If it is in the process of closing and it detects a person, it doesn't wait until it is completely closed before it reopens. It stop the closing process immediately and starts to reopen. Same thing when when the door is opening, stops mid-opening and closes back

Comment: @AceInteract I'd suggest to place the example in your comment above to your question to make the question more concrete.  I also fixed the issue you mentioned at a second click, by hiding the button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

building off of @themefield's answer above - thanks, @themefield! - this way works the 'best', not perfect.  (Sometimes the letter isn't in exactly the right spot when it reverses.)

The approach that worked was
a) reset animation to forward / reverse at the end
b) replace the animation with its opposite on toggling, setting a - start time to try to position it where it was.

Often it works pretty good, sometimes a lot off.

```js
span = document.querySelector('span')
button = document.querySelector('button')
timerElement = document.querySelector('#timerId')
duration = 3; // animation-during

let startTime = Date.now();
toSec = (msec) => msec / 1000
elapsedTimeMsec = () => Date.now() - startTime
elapsedTimeSec = () => toSec(elapsedTimeMsec())
updateTimer = () =>     timerElement.innerHTML = `${elapsedTimeSec().toPrecision(2)}s`

let intervalHandle;

startTimer = () => {
    intervalHandle = window.setInterval(() => {
        updateTimer()
    }, 500)
}

endTimer = () => {
    window.clearInterval(intervalHandle)
    intervalHandle = null
}

span.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
    startTime = Date.now();
    startTimer()
});

span.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => span.style.animationPlayState = 'paused');

toggleAnimation = (shouldDelay) => {
    span.classList.remove('my_anim');
    void span.offsetWidth;
    span.classList.add('my_anim');
    if(span.style.animationDirection !== 'reverse')
        span.style.animationDirection = 'reverse';
    else
        span.style.animationDirection = 'normal';
    if(shouldDelay !== null && shouldDelay) {
        span.style.animationDelay = `-${elapsedTimeSec()}s`;
    } else {
        span.style.animationDelay = `0s`;
    }
    span.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
}
span.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    endTimer()
    updateTimer()

    toggleAnimation();
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    endTimer()
    updateTimer()
    toggleAnimation(true) // todo pass in delay!
});
```

```css
span.my_anim {
            font-size: 54px;
            animation: 3s 1 normal both my_move;
        }

        @keyframes my_move {
            from {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            to {
                margin-left: 50%;
            }
        }

        button {
            /*visibility: hidden;*/
        }
        #timerId {
            font-size: 24px;
            color: darkturquoise;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="my_anim">@</span>
</div>
<button>reverse</button>
<span id="timerId"></span>
```